# Show that the Lebesgue measure of a solution set is finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would really appreciate some feedback on the following proof. I think/hope there might be a "less wordy" solution (using basic real analysis/measure theory), if so, any hints would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

---

Let

$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1/n^3}1_{[-n,n)}(x) \ \ , \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}$

and let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

I want to prove that:

For every  $\epsilon>0$ and $A_\epsilon = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x)>\epsilon  \}$, it holds that $\lambda(A_\epsilon)<\infty$

---

My attempt at a solution:

**1**


The result is trivial for $\epsilon \geq M = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^{3}$ (which is finite), Since $ A_M = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x)>M  \} = \emptyset $ . By definition of a measure; $\lambda(\emptyset)=0 < \infty$

**2**


I now proceed with the case $\epsilon \in (0,M)$.


I first note that $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing in the sense that

$$
|x_1| \leq |x_2| \implies f(x_1) \geq f(x_2) \\ \\ \iff  \\ \\
f(x_1) < f(x_2) \implies  |x_1| > |x_2| 
$$

By definition of $A_\epsilon$ this means that

$$
f(x_1) \leq f(x_2) \implies A_{f(x_2)} \subset A_{f(x_1)} \land [ \forall x \in A_{f(x_2)} : |x|<|x_1| ]
$$

And if $x_1<\infty$ then, by monotonicity of measures, it holds that 
$$
\lambda(A_{f(x_2)}) \leq \lambda(A_{f(x_1)}) = \lambda([-x_1,x_1)) < \infty
$$

Thus the proof is complete if i can show that for every $\epsilon$, there exists an  $x_0 < \infty$ such that $f(x_0) < \epsilon$ . By definition of $f(x)$, the existence of such an $x_0$ follows from the existence of a $k$ such that $ \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} 1/n^3 < \epsilon$ . Such a $k$ exists, due to the fact that

$$\forall r<M \exists e \in \mathbb{N} : r < \sum_{n=1}^{e} 1/n^3 < M$$

This implies that the expression   $M-\sum_{n=1}^{e} 1/n^3 = \sum_{n=e+1}^{\infty} 1/n^3$ can be made arbitrarily small, for sufficiently large $e$ .

Comment: You could also prove (using monotone convergence) that $f$ is integrable. You can then use (e.g.) the Markov inequality to finish the proof. This would be more efficient.

Comment: I think your proof is just fine - in fact, I wouldn't even do case 1, since case 2 never used $\epsilon < M$. It's possible you could do the same proof in fewer words, but in terms of ideas it's perfectly straightforward to me.

Comment: Many thanks! (would upvote if I could, but my reputation isnt high enough)